# Logentries and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, logentries

I am using logentries with Rails
My environment is deployed on AWS and when I tried to look at my rails logs from logentries I don't see a status response or any parameter but when I ssh in my instances and I tail the logs I can see these details.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to look at is how you have connected your instance to logentries...

Are these "static" instances or are they autoscaling ones?
Are you using an agent or another method?

if you are using the agent then a `le whoami` will give you some starting data about what's going on.

I have just got mine going in autoscaling groups with our rails apps using token based logging which isn't all that well documented and now seems to be working well.